# How to report child pipeline results from the parent pipeline in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, yaml, cicd, gitlab-ci.yml

Parent pipeline:

```
PA-JOB-A:  
  trigger:
    include:
      - local: $SERV/.gitlab-ci.yml
```

Child pipeline:

```
JUNIT-Tests:
  #rest of the job

  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - $SERV/target/surefire-reports/*.xml
    reports:
      junit: $SERV/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml
```

Currently, test results visually accessible only by opening each trigger job (downstreams) separately. I want to view all test results in the main pipeline view.

This is my main pipeline tests view:
[image]

I have to open downstreams separately:
[image]

How to report test results in the child pipeline from the parent pipeline so I can view tests in the main view? Or is there another way that I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no solution for this right now. There is an open issue for this: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/363019